# MVC Pattern: Displaying Result Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm very new to ASP.Net MVC but very familiar with the ASP.Net classic. I've been trying to learn the MVC pattern and I've come across this question. Let's say I have a database and I'd like to show some data from a table automatically in the home page. So far I have created a Model called the DemoModel, but I'm handling this task this way:

```
// This is not a contoller 
class ShowData {

public static DataContext DC = new DataContext ("My Connection String");

public static IEnumerable<DemoModel> GetData () {

   var Query = DC.GetTable<DemoModel>().ToList();   
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        yield return Query[i];
   }

}
```

and then using the Razor

```
@{
    var Query = ShowData.GetData().OrderBy(x=> x.Date);
    foreach (var i in Query) {
        <div> i.First </div>
        <div>i.Last </div>
         ......
    }
 }
```

My question is related to the MVC pattern, of course I can achive what I want this way, but is it the right way to display data in MVC or do I have to do everything inside the appropriate conrtroller ? if so How can I return what I want in the controller ?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc has decent tutorial explaining nicely. Please read that and your question will be answered!

Answer (score 1):

Well what you are doing isn't wrong. Could it be cleaner? Sure. For instance adding a for loop in your view is not favored. You can try perhaps binding your model to an @Html.Listbox